# Is there any research on the effectiveness of Google One tap sign up and sign in implementation for sites/apps?

Tags: signup-signon, google

I'm having a hard time finding anything related to if Google's One tap sign up and sign (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) in really helps or drives sign-in/up. Not even finding much anecdotal evidence.

Maybe it's worth A|B testing for a short time.

Comment: Did you see this case study? Is this helpful? https://developers.google.com/identity/casestudies/pinterest-casestudy.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I must of missed that. A CS published by Google isn't exactly neutral. I guess I'll just have to implement the feature, and run some tests against internal business goals. I'll report back here my findings as an answer.

Comment: I think it is worth clarifying or understanding the problem that you are trying to address or understand here. It would be good to point out a specific part of the feature that you think causes user experience issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that only Google would have the answer to the question, and that no doubt they would be testing this feature for the purpose of improving sign up and the sign in experience. And since it is hard to know the neutrality of Google's published research, and that they cover such a wide range of audience and user's, I think that it is difficult to get an objective answer to this question.

Even [case studies that are written about this feature](https://scandiweb.com/blog/google-one-tap-sign-in-brings-in-600-new-customer-accounts/) can also be biased, because they might be people who are trying to help people implement this feature, or just don't like Google's way of doing this. I guess you'll just have to make a best guess judgement for yourself and your users.